# How can I create an automatically updating count of cells with certain text and conditions in Excel?

Tags: excel

Imagine I have the following table:

| Category 1 | Category 2 |
| --- | --- |
| **A** | [Z] |
| D | Y |
| **A** | Y |

I want to make a formula that will count however many times A appears *when category 2 says [Z] and not Y*. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Thank you in advance! It would be super helpful and greatly appreciated.

I've tried a COUNTA formula with a filter inside of it, but it doesn't seem to be able to filter category 2. So in the example above, I'd get 2 as a result instead of 1

Comment: [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)?

Answer (score 0):

Simple `COUNTIFS` formula will help you:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"A",B:B,"[Z]")
```

Result:

[image]